# Is it possible to wrap/"chain" heuristic dissectors in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to extend an existing built-in heuristic dissector (it dissects infiniband-mads) to support more payload types.
I want to implement my extension as a plug-in, **without** changing the original dissector.

The existing dissector can parse the header and some of the payload types,
So I still want the dissection done by the existing one to be performed even for the additional types.

I found an example in Lua doing something similar at the end of [this page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors),
but it doesn't seem applicable in my case since there doesn't seem to be a way to "replace" a dissector in a heuristic dissector-table with another.

Is there some way to add support for the additional payload types (preferably not using C), without changing the code for the original dissector?

**EDIT:**

The original dissector registers in the "infiniband.payload" table.

Comment: There are two heuristic dissector tables in the Infiniband dissector - "infiniband.payload" and "infiniband.mad.cm.private".  In which of those tables does that heuristic dissector register?  (There doesn't appear to be any "infiniband-mads" dissector in the Wireshark source.)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you want - you want to replace the original dissector with your wrapper of the original dissector, which would use the base dissector, and then do some additional processing?

Comment: @GuyHarris It registers under "infiniband.payload".

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis - Yes, that is what I want. But I'm also OK with any other method that can extend the existing dissector without changing it.

Comment: The dissectors in Wireshark that register in the "infiniband.payload" table are 1) Fibre Channel over Infiniband, 2) Infiniband SDP, 3) iSER Infiniband, 4) Infiniband RPC over RDMA, 5) SMB Direct Infiniband, and 6) Shared Memory Communications Infiniband.  Is the dissector in question one of those, or is it a third-party dissector?

Comment: @GuyHarris
It's 1 of those - in line #2365 of packet-infiniband.c there is a check for management datagrams (MADs) and after that a parsing function is called depending on the management class.
What I want is to add parsing for more management classes (which are currently parsed generically as "vendor specific")

Comment: That's in `parse_PAYLOAD()`, which is called from `dissect_infiniband_common()`, which is not called from any heuristic dissector whatsoever - so how are heuristic dissectors involved at all here?  It sounds as if what's needed here is a change to Wireshark's built-in Infiniband dissector to add to it dissector tables to allow third-party dissectors to register for particular management classes.

Comment: Thanks!
Is there anything that can be done without changing the existing built-in dissector?
And if not - how should I go about changing the built-in dissector as you suggested? how much time/effort will it require?